# Exclude "_id" while using mongoexport

Tags: regex, linux, mongodb

I found the following solution on Stackoverflow and it works but I didn't understand how sed worked. Can anyone please elaborate the regex function in the following command.

**mongoexport --db db_name --collection collection_name | sed '/"_id":/s/"_id":[^,]*,//' > file_name.json**

Comment: hello, you can try regex here https://regex101.com one by one

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/Dxvbz9/1